# MySQL query taking too long to finish

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using MySQL Database and following query:

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    customer_code, 
    customer_name,  
    customer_address,
    customer_home_town
FROM  
    customers
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            issue_entry_customer_id,
            SUM(issue_entry_copies
              +issue_entry_subscribe
              +issue_entry_freecopies) AS col_copies 
        FROM 
            issue_entry 
        WHERE 
            issue_entry_deleted_status = 0  AND
            DATE_FORMAT(issue_entry_date,'%Y-%m') 
                = '".dateDatabaseFormat($issue_date)."'     
        GROUP BY 
            issue_entry_customer_id
    ) col_table 
        ON issue_entry_customer_id = customer_id
            AND customer_code = 1
            AND col_table.col_copies != 0
    ORDER BY
        customer_id ASC
```

**issue_entry** table has over 500 000 rows.

How can I improve the performance?

Comment: It's full query only

Answer (score 0):

Your query using some alias for better readablility.

```
select
c.customer_id, 
c.customer_code, 
c.customer_name,  
c.customer_address,
c.customer_home_town
from customers c
inner join (
 SELECT 
 issue_entry_customer_id, 
 SUM(issue_entry_copies+issue_entry_subcripe+issue_entry_freecpoies) AS col_copies 
 FROM issue_entry 
 WHERE 
 issue_entry_deleted_status = 0  AND
 DATE_FORMAT(issue_entry_date,'%Y-%m') = '".dateDatabaseFormat($issue_date)."'                 
 GROUP BY 
 issue_entry_customer_id
)x
on x.issue_entry_customer_id = c.customer_id
and c.customer_code   = 1
and x.col_copies != 0  
order BY customer_id ASC
```

Now the for large data you certainly needed to add some indexes to boostup the query.

```
alter table issue_entry add index i_del_date(issue_entry_deleted_status,issue_entry_date);
alter table issue_entry add index i_cid_idx(issue_entry_customer_id);
alter table customers add index c_code_idx(customer_code);
```

if `customer_id` in customer table is not primary key you may need to index that as well

```
alter table customers add index c_customer_id_idx(customer_id);
```

Also note that even with the `issue_entry_date` being indexed it may fail to use index since you are formatting the date.

Make sure to take a backup of the tables before applying the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
table_name alias INNER JOIN table_name2 alias ON ...
```

that's how INNER JOIN query is. Why are you doing a select after the INNER JOIN statement?

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_code, c.customer_name, 
       c.customer_address, c.customer_home_town
FROM customers c INNER JOIN
      (SELECT issue_entry_customer_id, 
              SUM(issue_entry_copies + issue_entry_subcripe + issue_entry_freecopies
              ) AS col_copies 
       FROM issue_entry ie
       WHERE issue_entry_deleted_status = 0  AND
             DATE_FORMAT(issue_entry_date, '%Y-%m')  = '".dateDatabaseFormat($issue_date)."'                 
      GROUP BY issue_entry_customer_id
     ) col_table
     ON col_table.issue_entry_customer_id = c.customer_id AND
        c.customer_code = 1 AND
        col_table.col_copies <> 0  
ORDER BY c.customer_id ASC;
```

My recommendation is to change the whole format of the query:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_code, c.customer_name, 
       c.customer_address, c.customer_home_town
FROM customers c
WHERE c.customer_code = 1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM issue_entry ie
              WHERE ie.issue_entry_customer_id = customer_id AND  
                    DATE_FORMAT(issue_entry_date, '%Y-%m')  = '".dateDatabaseFormat($issue_date)."' AND
                    ie.issue_entry_deleted_status = 0 AND
                    (issue_entry_copies > 0 OR
                     issue_entry_subcripe > 0 OR
                     issue_entry_freecopies
                    )
             )
ORDER BY customer_id ASC;
```

Note:  this assumes that the three columns are never negative.

For this query, you want the following indexes:  `customers(customer_code, customer_id)` and `issue_entry(issue_entry_customer_id, issue_entry_deleted_status)`.